# Change typename type into the template function (c++)

Tags: c++, function, templates, typename

So I'm currently working on upgrading my skills with templates and I'm stuck with something.

I want to, if one of my objects uses `floating_point` numbers and I do math operation with another object which is of type integral, to return an object of type floating point.
But I can only know when they're already in the function and I would like to know if there is a way to force our typename to be some defined type.

**EDIT:** I saw that my post lacked of example so I will show you the function I'm working on.

```
// Addition : +
template <typename TYP_O1, typename TYP_O2, typename TYP_RE> 
requires (std::integral<TYP_O1> || std::floating_point<TYP_O1>) &&(std::integral<TYP_O2> || std::floating_point<TYP_O2>)

MultiArray<TYP_RE> operator+(MultiArray<TYP_O1>& rMultiArr1, MultiArray<TYP_O2>& rMultiArr2){
    // Création d'un array qui sera la somme des deux MultiArray un à un
    std::vector<TYP_RE> Array;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < (int)rMultiArr1.getArray().size() ; i++) {
        // On les récupère par référence pour faciliter la lecture.
        std::vector<TYP_O1>& Arr1 = rMultiArr1.getArray();
        std::vector<TYP_O2>& Arr2 = rMultiArr2.getArray();

        // On rajoute la somme à la fin du Array
        Array.push_back((TYP_RE)Arr1[i] + Arr2[i]);
     }

    // On crée le MultiArray de la somme des 2
    MultiArray<TYP_RE> result_MultiArr = {rMultiArr1.getDim(), rMultiArr1.getShape(), Array};

    // On renvoie ce MultiArray nouvellement crée
    return result_MultiArr;
}
```

(I've just erased the errors check)

So in the template: `TYP_O1` is the type of the first object and `TYP_O2` is the type of the second object.

`TYP_RE` is the return type and **THIS** is the typename that I want to force to be a double if one of the `MultiArray` is of type `"floating_point"` (and the other one is "integral")

Comment: Whether it's possible entirely depends on the types used in your function declaration. Perhaps you can post a more complete example? The short answer is that you cannot just set some `Type` to `double` but rather dictate that the return type will be a `double` when certain properties about types used in the declaration are met. A slightly longer answer is that if the type may be 1 of N types at runtime, you'll want a `variant`

Comment: Do you want `std::conditional_t`?

Comment: Maybe trailing return value is all you need. But give that your question does not have as adequate example, it is hard to know. In C++, there are many ways to do things. We need a concerte example to tell you which one is best. Or you could simply read a book if you want to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) to choose a type based on a condition.

A basic example:

```
template<typename LHS, typename RHS>
auto plus(LHS lhs, RHS rhs) -> std::conditional_t<
    std::is_same_v<LHS, double> || std::is_same_v<LHS, double>,
    double,
    int
> {
    return lhs + rhs;
}
```

The return type of `plus` will be `double` if either of the arguments is a `double`, otherwise it will be `int`. Note that it doesn't make much sense here because `lhs + rhs` is already a `double` if either `lhs` or `rhs` is (assuming they are basic arithmetic types, not including `long double` or pointer types).

In your case (since you've added a code snippet), your could do something like this:

```
template<typename TYP_O1, typename TYP_O2>
using MultiArraySumResult = std::conditional_t<
    std::is_floating_point_v<TYP_01>,
    MultiArray<TYP_01>,
    MultiArray<TYP_02>
>
// or...
template<typename TYP_O1, typename TYP_O2>
using MultiArraySumResult = MultiArray<std::conditional_t<
    std::is_floating_point_v<TYP_01> || std::is_floating_point_v<TYP_02>,
    double,
    int
>>
```

Then you just use `MultiArraySumResult<TYP_O1, TYP_O2>` as your return type. You can even no specify the return type (`auto` without trailing return type), put that `using` declaration inside the function, and use it for the local variable that you return:

```
template <typename TYP_O1, typename TYP_O2, typename TYP_RE> 
requires (std::integral<TYP_O1> || std::floating_point<TYP_O1>) &&(std::integral<TYP_O2> || std::floating_point<TYP_O2>)
auto operator+(MultiArray<TYP_O1>& rMultiArr1, MultiArray<TYP_O2>& rMultiArr2){
    using ReturnType = std::conditional_t<
        is_floating_point_v<TYP_01>,
        MultiArray<TYP_01>,
        MultiArray<TYP_02>
    >
    ReturnType Array;
    // [...]
    return ReturnType{rMultiArr1.getDim(), rMultiArr1.getShape(), Array};
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks ! I think this is the command i needed.

But, what is the difference between "std::conditional" and "std::conditional_t" ?

Comment: @lordeji Check out the linked page. In general, `std::trait_t<Ts...>` is an alias for `std::trait<Ts...>::type`.